# The place of verbs in questions

Tags: verbs, word-order

- > What colour *was* Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun?
- > What *was* the colour of Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun?
- > What colour Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun *was*?
- > What colour Tom Cruise's jacket *was* in Top Gun?

Which ones of these questions are correct? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only two that are correct are:

1. What colour was Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun?
2. What was the colour of Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun?

Word order tends to be very strict in English.

In both (1) and (2), we find this pattern:

*Wh-word + auxiliary verb + Subject?*

The only difference is that in (1) "what" accompanies the noun "colour", while in (2) "what" is used as a pronoun. The same two options can be found with other magnitudes, like "size" or "shape":

- **What size** was his jacket?
- **What** was the size of his jacket?
- **What shape** was his hat?
- **What** was the shape of his hat?

Answer (score 0):

> What colour was Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun?
>
> What was the colour of Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun?

Both of these are correct, and have the same meaning.

> What colour Tom Cruise's jacket in Top Gun was?

This is incorrect.  English uses the [SVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object) grammatical structure, which can include sentences that look like SV, SVC, SVO, SVOO, and SVOC. (see [link](https://www.scribd.com/doc/109551389/The-Five-Sentence-Structures-SV-SVC-SVO-SVOO-SVOC) for more details)

Only the SV sentence structure ends in a verb, which is for very simple sentences with no direct object only.  These would be very simple sentences such as "He ran.  The dog jumps.  I helped."  By raising the vocal pitch of the final word, you can turn these simple sentences into implied questions: "He ran?"

However, your question requires an object.  Any sentence with an object *cannot* have the verb at the end of the sentence.

> What colour Tom Cruise's jacket was in Top Gun?

For you, as an English Language Learner, this is incorrect.  It can technically, under very specific contexts, be considered correct English.  Those contexts are rare and contrived, and the meaning would be completely different than the meaning you seem to be looking for.

Comment: What if a "there is/there are" were to be put on? For example: ""There is a red carpet in the kitchen". Which of the questions can be regarded as acceptable: 1."What colour is the carpet there in the kitchen?", 2."What colour is the carpet in the kitchen?", 3."What colour carpet is there in the kitchen?", 4."What coloured carpet is there in the kitchen?". Thank you